# Using the 3rd parameter of a function

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function, parameters

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the 3rd parameter of the getLowest/getHighest function to reference the names array that has the months of the year and display the names of the month when I call for it? What's supposed to happen with those  functions is that they are supposed to be able to give the name of the month that corresponds with the lowest/highest amount in the array. I can't seem to get it down. That's the last thing I need for this code and I'm trying very hard to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
double getTotal(double [], int);
double getAverage(double [], int);
double getLowest(double [], int, int&);
double getHighest(double [], int, int&);

int main()
{
    const int months = 12;
    string names[months] = { "January", "February", "March", "April",
        "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    double rainfall[months];
    double total, average, maxRain, minRain;
    int indexofLowest, indexofHighest;

    //Input from using for the rainfall amounts
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of rainfall in inches, that fell in each month.\n";
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[0];
    std::cin >> rainfall[0];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[1];
    std::cin >> rainfall[1];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[2];
    std::cin >> rainfall[2];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[3];
    std::cin >> rainfall[3];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[4];
    std::cin >> rainfall[4];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[5];
    std::cin >> rainfall[5];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[6];
    std::cin >> rainfall[6];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[7];
    std::cin >> rainfall[7];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[8];
    std::cin >> rainfall[8];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[9];
    std::cin >> rainfall[9];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[10];
    std::cin >> rainfall[10];
    std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << names[11];
    std::cin >> rainfall[11];

    //Get total
    total = getTotal(rainfall, months);

    //Get average
    average = getAverage(rainfall, months);

    //Get the max amount of rain
    maxRain = getHighest(rainfall, months, indexofHighest);

    //Get the min amount of rain
    minRain = getLowest(rainfall, months, indexofLowest);

    //Display the total, average, highest/lowest
    std::cout << "The total amount of rain for the year is " << total << " inches.\n";
    std::cout << "The average amount of rain monthly is " << average << " inches per month.\n";
    std::cout << "The month that had the highest amount of rainfall is " << names[indexofHighest] << " with " << maxRain << " inches.\n";
    std::cout << "The month that has the lowest amount of rainfall is " << names[indexofLowest] << " with " << minRain << " inches.\n";
    return 0;

}

//Definition of function getTotal
double getTotal(double rainfall[], int months)
{
    double total = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < months; count++)
    {
        total += rainfall[count];
    }
    return total;
}

//Definition of function getAverage
double getAverage(double rainfall[], int months)
{
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0.0;
    for (int count = 0; count < months; count++)
    {
        total += rainfall[count];
        average = total / months;
    }
    return average;
}

//Defintion of function getLowest
double getLowest(double rainfall[], int months, int indexofLowest)
{

    int count;
    double lowest;

    lowest = rainfall[0];
    for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
    {
        if (rainfall[count] < lowest)
            lowest = rainfall[count];
    }
    return lowest;
}

//Definition of function getHighest
double getHighest(double rainfall[], int months, int indexofHighest)
{
    int count;
    double highest;

    highest = rainfall[0];
    for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
    {
        if (rainfall[0] > highest)
            highest = rainfall[count];
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Comment: Your `getLowest` and `getHighest` functions don't actually set `indexofLowest`/`indexofHighest`... Also, their definitions don't match their prototypes.

Comment: You could simplify your program by using a `for` loop to enter the rainfall data; or better, place the data into a file, read from the file.  The file method means you don't have to keep entering the data by hand each time.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions guys. Like @immibis said, I just set the indexofLowest / indexofHighest in the functions to count and everything was fixed. A lot simpler of a fix than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. You have a few bugs. I guess you need to try harder in the future. Anyways here is a working solution with minimal changes to your existing code -

```
//Defintion of function getLowest                                                                                               
double getLowest(double rainfall[], int months, int & indexofLowest)
{
    int count;
    double lowest;

    lowest = rainfall[0];
    for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
    {
        if (rainfall[count] < lowest)
        {
                        lowest = rainfall[count];
                        indexofLowest = count;
        }
    }

return lowest;
}

//Definition of function getHighest
double getHighest(double rainfall[], int months, int & indexofHighest)
{
    int count;
    double highest;

    highest = rainfall[0];
    for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
    {
                if (rainfall[count] > highest)
                {       
                        highest = rainfall[count];
                        indexofHighest = count;
                }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Comment: Didn't realize of simple of a fix that was. To just set indexofHighest and indexofLowest to count. I gotta do better of looking for the little things. @Samboy786

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `indexofLowest` and `indexofHighest` in your functions (and match their prototype):

```
//Defintion of function getLowest
double getLowest(double rainfall[], int months, int& indexofLowest)

int count;
double lowest;

lowest = rainfall[0];
for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
{
    if (rainfall[count] < lowest) {
    lowest = rainfall[count];
    indexofLowest = count;
    }
}
return lowest;
}

//Definition of function getHighest
double getHighest(double rainfall[], int months, int& indexofHighest)
{
int count;
double highest;

highest = rainfall[0];
for (count = 1; count < months; count++)
{
    if (rainfall[count] > highest) { //there was a bug here in your code: ... rainfall[0]
        highest = rainfall[count];
        indexofHeighest = count;
    }
}
return highest;
}
```

you can also use a function to input data (and maybe add a little error checking):

```
//Input from using for the rainfall amounts
int readData(string monthNames[], double rain[], int n) {
    int i;
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of rainfall in inches, that fell in each month.\n";
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter the amount of rainfall for " << monthNames[i];
        std::cin >> rain[i]; //check this value somehow!
    }
    return i;   
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. Didn't realize how simple of a fix that was. @Bob__